# Tengo un problema con npm

Tags: npm

Tengo un problema al instalar paquetes con npm, me da este error

`npm ERR! code ECONNRESET`

Y no me deja instalar nada

Soy de cuba y no estoy seguro si npm esta disponible, pero intento con un VPN y tampoco funciona

Comment: sistema operativo?

Comment: Además de darte ese error estoy *cuasi* seguro de que también te añade una línea que dice algo como *"more information on XXXX_XXX.log"*, esa es la información que necesitamos ver. Si solo nos dices "me da error" pero no vemos el error, cómo podemos saber qué está pasando?? Seas de cuba, de españa o de la antártica, sin saber qué error te da es imposible ayudarte. Utiliza el enlace [edit] y añade absolutamente toda la información necesaria para la pregunta.